# XPages: is it possible to flush HTML?

Tags: html, jsf, xpages

We'd like to show a "Loading..." image when the page is still being transferred. Pages can get quite large in our application. I tried with a separate page that displays the image and then loads the intended page, but the animated GIF just stops.

Can something be done on the page itself?
Or is there a better way?

Thanks for your comments, as always!

---

UPDATE

Here's the general idea of my small switching page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xp:div
        style="width:84.0px;height:84.0px;position:fixed;top:50%;left:50%;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px;height:0px;width:0px;z-index:1000"
        id="AjaxLoader">
        <xp:image url="/loading.gif" id="image1">
        </xp:image>
    </xp:div>
    <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[XSP.addOnLoad(function() {
    var href= getParameterByName("href");
    location.href= href;
});]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading a "loading" page prior than the one you want to load is not an option.

You can create to DIVs in your HTML: one for the loading icon (e.g. with id="loadingIcon"), second one for the content (id="contentWrapper"). The second one is hidden (CSS style="display:none").

Define a Javascript function like this:

```
function pageLoaded(){
   document.getElementById("loadingIcon").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("contentWrapper").style.display = "";
}
```

The script is called in the BODY's onLoad event like this:

```
<body onload="pageLoaded()">
...
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that: I added a div, similar to the idea above, but nothing is displayed in Firefox until the entire page is loaded. That could be because the page is loaded in an iFrame and it uses dojo tab-panes. I know there are other web-server environments that support some kind of flush(), so how about JSF/XPages? I might try again though, with your pageLoaded function... :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a question of the web-server environment, but how you organize your code :-)

Take your approach and modify it slightly. Instead of `location.href = href` - which just triggers a reload, use an ajax call and replace your loading div. Something like this:

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[XSP.addOnLoad(function() {
var href= getParameterByName("href");
$.ajax({
   url: "test.html",
   context: $("#{id:AjaxLoader}");
 }).done(function(result) {
   $( this ).replace(result);
});
location.href= href;
});]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

(contains typos, adjust as needed)

Comment: I solved my problem differently, and it's a completely different approach. As I said, we use iframes, and the main page contains only one tab pane with 4 tabs with an iframe each. So I put my AjaxLoader element in the top window, and each sub-window checks whether its parent has the AjaxLoader element. If so, it uses it, otherwise it creates a new one. To be more precise, I create a CSJS object that I store in window.AjaxLoader, and each sub-frame checks whether there is a parent.AjaxLoader. One element, one object, the top frame is never reloaded, hence the AjaxLoader div is always available.

Comment: @D.Bugger: It wouldn't make any sense to add a *flush* on top of JSF/XPages. But the *HttpServletResponse* has a *flush()* method, so you could generate your own HTML output and flush it to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: No, it's not possible, but there is a nice way around this, in my case anyway.

The trick is to open a new browser window, write something in it and then allow the new page to load.

```
var w= window.open();
w.document.write("<div style='position: fixed; top: 48%; left:40%'>Loading...</div>");
w.location.href= url;
```

If necessary the text can be replaced by an image and the new url can be set after a timeout.